# How do I recover from overwriting a merge file in git?

Tags: git, git-merge

I just made a mistake with my git repo (stupid programming while Dayquil'd).  My steps were:

1. start editing file.txt
2. did a "git pull" on the repo containing file.txt.  File.txt was part of a merge conflict.
3. did some edits on the version of file.txt I opened in step 1.
4. saved the file I opened in step 1, overwriting the merge.
5. ???

I need to resolve the merge from step 2, and then merge that result with the edits made in step 2.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you still have the merge blocks in the file?

Comment: Did you ever complete the merge?

Comment: @jcm, no, I do not, if by merge blocks, you mean <<<<< etc.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, no-- I pulled, didn't realize I needed to merge, and then saved over the merge.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your problem is simply that you overwrote the file and lost the merge conflict markers. The simplest way to deal with this is to use `git mergetool`, which will use a GUI merge tool to deal with conflicts. This tool doesn't rely on the working copy version of the file with conflict markers, it actually re-merges the original files using the GUI tool of your choice. I highly recommend it as your normal go-to solution for merge conflicts.

If you really do want the file back with the conflict markers, you can just use `git checkout -m -- file.txt`. This will re-create the merge conflict version of the file. Note that any changes you made in steps 3 and 4 will be lost.

If you want to save the local changes you made, you can use `git diff :2:file.txt file.txt` to view a diff between your pre-merge copy of file.txt and the copy you saved to disk. You can pipe this to a file in order to use later to re-create your changes after you solve the merge, or even use `git apply` with the file to apply it as a patch (as long as it doesn't touch any hunks that the merge changed).

Comment: @KevinBallard-- would favoretti's stash idea help to keep the step 3 and 4 changes?

Comment: @mmr: Probably not. I'm not quite sure what `git stash` will do if you run it in your current state, since I'm not really sure what `git diff -- file.txt` will actually print in your current state. You might try something like `git diff :2:file.txt file.txt`, which *might* give you a diff between your previous version of file.txt (before the merge) and your current version that you saved to disk, but I can't be certain without testing (and I don't have a merge conflict handy to test with). If it does work, you can just pipe that to a file for safekeeping.

Comment: @mmr: Yeah, `git stash` will error out in your current state. `git diff` will print a conflict-style diff which is highly confusing. However `git diff :2:file.txt file.txt` will print exactly what you want, which is the changes you made.

Comment: @KevinBallard-- this may sound nuts (ie, the 'quil talking)-- but what about reverting to what's in head, but saving the work I currently have open in another file.  Then, I create a branch, and then save the edits from the other file into the same file.txt.  Then, I should be able to merge branches, right?

Comment: @KevinBallard-- it doesn't help that git diff is choosing the wrong versions of the portions of the text file; it's saying that my most recent edits are right, since they are more recent.  gah.

Comment: @mmr: What do you mean? the `:2:file.txt` argument specifically refers to the version of file.txt that you had pre-merge, and the bare `file.txt` refers to the version of the file that's currently in the working copy. So `git diff :2:file.txt file.txt` will show the changes you made in your editor, ignoring the changes introduced by the pull.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
git checkout --merge -- file.txt
```

Comment: If this does what I think it does, that's pretty awesome.

Comment: Note, this is exactly the same as `git checkout -m -- file.txt`, which I suggested in my answer.